# Whats <A-> in neovim key bindng?

Tags: neovim

I'm using this [neovim plugin](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope-file-browser.nvim) and in the docs there are multiple mentions of keybinding with `<A-something>`. I know that `<C-anykey>` means, `Ctrl+anykey`. But I cannot find any reference in the internet about `<A`. At first I assumed it is the `Alt` key but it doesn't seem to work.

I also can't find the documentation about these key bindings. The docs I've read always say `<C-key` it doesn't even mention that `<C>` is `Control` Key. At first I thought it was just capital letter `C`.I'm using `vim` for two years now. This time I want to switch to `neovim`. But i'm still a noob when it comes to key bindings until now.

Please point me to the right direction as I'm totally lost here.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, `<A>` is the `Alt` key. I found the [answer](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope-file-browser.nvim/issues/185#issuecomment-1264719666) by posting the question to the repository of the said plugin I mentioned above. The [Neovim documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/map.html) about key mapping still does not mention `<A>` as `Alt` key, but they refer to it as `ALT`.